# Strange activity from many to many in grails

Tags: grails, many-to-many

Hi I am getting some strange activity from a many to many in grails.
It seems to be calling its self recursively.

my domains are set up like:

Product domain:

```
 class Product {
     String name
     String comments
     static hasMany = [components:Components]
 }
```

Component domain:

```
 class Components {
     Product product
     static hasMany = [alternatives:Product]
     static belongsTo = Product
 }
```

This seems to be causing a infinate loop and not saving the components correctly.
I know when using JSON.use("deep") on a Product I get a ../.. in components. The next strange thing is that. If I as for a product as JSON after I saved that product everything works fine, but when I try and get the same product as JSON later I get the ../.. in components.

I am totally lost about this.

If you require more details please let me know and I will me best to comply.

Comment: I'd remove `static hasMany = [alternatives:Product]` and put it in another domain class if needed. many-to-many relations cause more troubles, than they try to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to have a many-to-many relationship you need to store the relationship data somewhere.  If your relationship was one-to-many you could store them in the client table (like how you already have a component having one specific product in your component table) but in many to many you need the relationship to be its own table.  To do this in Grails, use the JoinTable attribute or create a separate domain class to handle the relationship.  Probably the fact that you have one-to-many relationship with Product already for Components and the many-to-many relationship with no join table is why you are getting the weird recursion issue.